# How to refresh Excel Formula at read

Tags: pandas

I want to use Excel sheet in pandas. The excel sheet has some automatic calculate formula base on the date of the day.

There are any way to update Excel formula before or during the open of Excel file in pandas.

Comment: This should be automatic when you read it in with pandas? what do you get when you read it in?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the formula will not be update when I read Excel File with the pandas.ExcelFile function.

Comment: pandas itself does not have capabilities to control Excel Application which is responsible for updating formulas on opening the file. pandas will read-in whatever values have been stored (saved) last. You might want to look at [xlwings](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/) library which allows to control Excel Application and export data to pandas data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

office = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = office.Workbooks.Open(your_file_path)
wb.RefreshAll()
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
df = pd.read_excel(your_file_path) #updates should be applied
```