# When writing values to Excel in Pandas, formulas based on those cells are not recalculated

Tags: excel, pandas, excel-formula

I am using below code for reading data, spliting it then writing it again. All actions are done correctly, but when I check in excel workbook, the values that correspond by excel function on data wrote by df.to_excel(), I found that function didn't recognize it, until I go to cell and open it then press enter.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel(io=IP+'.xlsx',sheet_name='VLAN', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel(io=IP+'.xlsx',sheet_name='Profile', header=None)
# Code to separate data
df1 = df1[0].str.split(' |:', expand=True)
df2 = df2[0].str.split(' |:', expand=True)

# Save and close the workbook
with pd.ExcelWriter(path=IP+'.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',if_sheet_exists='replace',mode='a') as write:
    df1.to_excel(write , sheet_name='VLAN', header=None, index=False)
    df2.to_excel(write , sheet_name='Profile', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh Excel Formula at read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466582/how-to-refresh-excel-formula-at-read)

Comment: yes, i used that a year ago, thanks